# Why is eclipse running ALL Junit tests in my class?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I've noticed an issue with running JUnit tests recently with Eclipse that when you request it to run a single test from a class (either from the JUnit view, or using the "Run As/Debug As JUnit test" context command from inside a function definition or even creating a new run or debug configuration that specifies a particular test name) it will always run ALL the tests in that class.  The same problem is occuring on a colleague's machine, so it's not something specific to my settings.
This never used to occur and I'm not sure when it started.  It means I actually have to disable/comment out the @Test annotation for all the tests I don't want to run, so is obviously quite annoying.
Anyone else observed this and even better, figured out how to fix?

Thanks!

(PS sorry if this doesn't technically qualify as a programming question, but there didn't seem too many other forums I'd be likely to get a better response).

Comment: which version of ecllipse are you using ?

Comment: 4.7.0, and I believe my colleague has a slightly later version

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) is pretty old. Please use the current version, Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13). If upgrading Eclipse does not fix your issue, please tell which JUnit version do you use and how the JUnit dependency is added (e.g. via Maven, Gradle, directly, etc.).

Comment: Now running 4.7.3a, same problem. Junit 4.12.  I understand there are some limitations with Eclipse 4.13 and the kotlin plugin (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KE-340) so I haven't been willing to try upgrading to that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was due to using BurstJunit4 (https://github.com/square/burst) - which doesn't appear to honour requests to run just a single test.
It still occurs even using latest IntelliJ etc.